# Ionic 2 Android Camera/Gallery Crash

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-camera, ionic2, cordova-plugins

For some reason, Ionic 2 and the "cordova-plugin-camera" keep crashing whenever I try to take or select a picture on an Android device. I have read that it could be due to low memory, but my device has 7gbs free. I have also read that it could be the "destinationType" which I had set as DATA_URL and changed to FILE_URI, but still found the same error.

I would appreciate any assistance in solving this error, as it works flawlessly on iOS.

Here is my code:

```
  openCamera() {
    Camera.getPicture({
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
      quality: 50,
      correctOrientation: true
    }).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
      // If it's base64:
      this.issue.image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  openGallery() {
    let cameraOptions = {
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: 1,
      quality: 50,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

    Camera.getPicture(cameraOptions)
      .then((file_uri) => {
          this.issue.image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + file_uri;
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this should be `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` since you are using `data:image/jpeg;base64` when you assign it to the image element

Comment: Yeah I definitely shouldn't be. I had it set at DATA_URL before, which is what I typically keep it at. Not the issue though. I can't even open up the promise because the app crashes before then.